# Coloring specific nodes in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a graph in networkx which I want to plot. Everything works fine, but I decided it would be useful to color specific nodes. How do I do this?

I have seen, that this can be done by using the command

```
draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=None, node_size=300, node_color='r', node_shape='o', alpha=1.0, cmap=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, ax=None, linewidths=None, label=None, **kwds)
```

by setting the color and cmap keyword to the right value. But all examples I have seen so far use `cmap=plt.get_cmap(some string)`, which is a standard function which does not seem helpful to me.

To clarify: I  have several list of nodes and I want to color all nodes in a list in the same color

Comment: AFAIK, specifing `cmap` only has an effect if you set `node_color` to some numeric value. If you just want to change the color all nodes are plotted in, it is completely sufficient to pass a different string argument for `node_color`. Available named colors can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw your nodes *in groups* based on color similar to the [example](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/examples/drawing/labels_and_colors.html) they provide. With each group that you draw, just specify `node_color` to the color that you want.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.cubical_graph()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nodes = {
    'r': [1, 3, 5],
    'b': [0, 2],
    'g': [4]
}
for node_color, nodelist in nodes.items():
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodelist, node_color=node_color)

labels = {x: x for x in G.nodes}
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=16, font_color='w')
```

[image]